# How do I mix MUST_PASS_ALL and MUST_PASS_ONE in HBase filters?

Tags: java, hbase

I have an HBase scan with a `ColumnPrefixFilter` and multiple `FuzzyFilter`s like so:

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList();
filterList.addFilter(new FuzzyFilter(...));
filterList.addFilter(new FuzzyFilter(...));
filterList.addFilter(new ColumnPrefixFilter(...));
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setFilter(filterList);
```

Is there a way I can use `MUST_PASS_ONE` on the `FuzzyFilter`s and then a `MUST_PASS_ALL` on the `ColumnPrefixFilter` combined with the set of `FuzzyFilter`s?

So I'm looking for something like this:

`ColumnPrefixFilter` AND (`FuzzyFilter` OR `FuzzyFilter`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement two different FilterList to acheive this. Refer the below code

```
    FilterList mainFilter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    FilterList subFilter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);

    subFilter.addFilter(new FuzzyRowFilter(null));
    subFilter.addFilter(new FuzzyRowFilter(null));

    mainFilter.addFilter(new ColumnPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("d")));
    mainFilter.addFilter(subFilter);
```

You can define a mainFilter with MUST_PASS_ALL operator and a subFilter with MUST_PASS_ONE. Now add the filter conditions into subFilter and then add back this subFilter into mainFilter.

Answer (score 1):

`FilterList` is a `Filter` itself, so just combine them

```
FilterList fuzzy = new FilterList(MUST_PASS_ONE, fuzzy1, fuzzy2);
FilterList main = new FilterList(MUST_PASS_ALL, prefixFilter, fuzzy);
s.setFilter(main);
```